# OneToMany Relationship Only Returns 1 Row

Tags: doctrine-orm, doctrine, one-to-many

I am looking for some help as to why my OneToMany relationship in doctrine only returns one value.  My data model has three tables. Users, Authorization, and Applications.  The Authorization table is the glue that maps users to applications and also contains an accesslevel field to indicate their level of access for that application.

I have a user that has three entries in authorization for three different applications, but for some reason, doctrine is only loading 1 of those authorization records.  I've included my full data model below. The attribute in question is "authorization" in the Webusers table.

Anyone know what I am doing wrong?

```
class Webusers {
/**
 * @var integer
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="userid", type="integer", nullable=false)
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="IDENTITY")
 */
private $userid;    
/**
 * @var \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection
 *
 * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Applications", mappedBy="userid")
 */
private $applications;

/**
 * @var \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection
 *
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Authorization", mappedBy="user")
 */
private $authorization;

/**
 * Constructor
 */
public function __construct() {
    $this->applications = new \Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection();
    $this->authorization = new \Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection();  
}

class Authorization {
/**
 * @var integer
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="accesslevel", type="integer", nullable=false)
 */
private $accesslevel;

/**
 * @var integer
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="applicationid", type="integer", nullable=false)
 * $ORM\Id
 */
private $applicationid;

/**
 * @var integer
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="userid", type="integer", nullable=false)
 * @ORM\Id
 */
private $userid;

 /**
 * @var \Webusers
 *
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Webusers")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="userid", referencedColumnName="userid")
 */
private $user;
}

class Applications {
/**
 * @var integer
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="applicationid", type="integer", nullable=false)
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="IDENTITY")
 */
private $applicationid;

/**
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="name", type="string", length=50, nullable=false)
 */
private $name;
/**
 * @var \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection
 *
 * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Webusers", inversedBy="applicationid")
 * @ORM\JoinTable(name="authorization",
 *   joinColumns={
 *     @ORM\JoinColumn(name="applicationid", referencedColumnName="applicationid")
 *   },
 *   inverseJoinColumns={
 *     @ORM\JoinColumn(name="userid", referencedColumnName="userid")
 *   }
 * )
 */
private $userid;

/**
 * Constructor
 */
public function __construct()
{
    $this->userid = new \Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection();
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix this by making sure I specified both the webusers and application relationship as ManyToOne AND giving them the @ORM\Id property since they make up a composite primary key.

I think the main reason this was failing was because I had not associated authorization to applications.

The key points of my new model are as follows:

```
class Webusers {
 /**
 * @var \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Authorization", mappedBy="user")
 */
 private $authorization;
 }

class Authorization {
/**
 *
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Applications")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="applicationid", referencedColumnName="applicationid")
 */
private $application;

 /**
 * 
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Webusers")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="userid", referencedColumnName="userid")
 */
private $user;
}

class Applications {
/**
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Authorization", mappedBy="application")
 */
 private $authorization;
}
```